# How to import one class from many classes on one python file

Tags: python

Here is is the directory structure:

```
 ->src/dir/classes.py
 ->src/run.py
```

```
# classes.py

class A():
   def methA():
      # class A

class B():
   def MethB():
      # class B

class C():
   def methC():
      # class C
```

then i need to import `Class A` in `run.py` file.

```
from dir.classes import A

A.methA()
```

i already tried with using `from dir.classes import A` but it gives me

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir.classes'; 'classes' is not a package` error

So how can i do that?

Comment: Can you post your `run.py` file?

Comment: How do you execute ``run.py``? Do you have a ``src/dir/__init__.py``? Is this Python2 or Python3?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, actually `run.py` is a flask app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put__init__.py file on your dir folder.
This way dir will be recognized as python package.

Comment: got it i'll try that way

Comment: Python3 has namespace packages. A folder without an ``__init__.py`` will still be considered a package.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must have `__init__.py` in each directory for Python to recognize them as packages.

Then, you should use `from dir.classes import A`. A is the name of the class, you shouldn't use `Class A`

Comment: yeah, it was a simple mistake, anyway thanks for notify